# Location Permission is not working

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

I want to check weather on device location but this line of code is not working when I click the button. **There are two activities**  namely 1st activity and 2nd activity. Codes and the Button are in the 2nd activity still it doesn't work. It does nothing at all. When I simply Log to the onLocation()-, it works but the location manager or listener doesn't. I think there would be something wrong with the context but don't know how to fix it. **But it works perfectly fine within a single activity**. Please help!

```
public void onLocation(View view){

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            String latitude = String.format("%.2f",location.getLatitude());
            String longitude = String.format("%.2f",location.getLongitude());


            DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
            String result = "";
            try {
                result = task.execute("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&appid=c940e43a5462f3c3b228e3812b747b25").get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("location weather",result);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
    }


}
```

Comment: What you have cannot work. An `AsyncTask` is, well--asynchronous. You cannot call `result = task.execute()` and expect "result" to contain any meaningful data. The "result" will be presented in the `onPostExecute()` method once `doInBackground()` is finished--and not before.

Comment: Ok but how I supposed to fix it then? @Barns